# Re-run robocopy for deltas

Tags: robocopy

Its been a while since Ive run a robocopy script. I copied about 5.5 TB of data to a new server via robocopy. Doing a data count, some files didnt get copied over -about 50-60. There were some interruptions so the log file wasnt complete from the start date.

If I re-run the script, will it start at the beginning and bypass all of the copied files and just do the deltas? Here is the script for the robocopy - `robocopy /e /r:0 /w:1`